# Looping through recordset and adding each row to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm looking for a solution to a problem I'm having when trying to loop through the recordset, grabbing the columns I need, add the values to a list and then adding the list to a dictionary value.

This works fine for the first record but after I try to clear the list out to insert the next 8 fields into the list, it's clearing out the existing list values from the Dictionary(after it's already added).

Is there a way to get around this?

```
List<string> dbList = new List<string>();
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dbDict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

do
{
dbList.Add("Field1 : " (String)rs.Fields["Field1"].Value);
dbList.Add("Field2 : " rs.Fields["Field 2"].Value);
dbList.Add("Field3 : " (String)rs.Fields["Field3"].Value);
dbDict.add(i,dbList);
i+=1;
rs.MoveNext();
dbList.Clear();
}
while (rs.EOF == false);
```

Comment: `dbList` is a reference object.  you only create one of them, so the same one is added (and cleared) over an over.  Create a new list to store new values

Comment: try `dbList = new List<string>();` instead of `dbList.Clear()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list every loop. That fix your problem. Because it's a reference type calling clear on it will cause that reference to clear -  including the one in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

try `dbList = new List<string>();` instead of `dbList.Clear()`

Solution:

```
List<string> dbList;
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dbDict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

do
{
    dbList = new List<string>();
    dbList.Add("Field1 : " (String)rs.Fields["Field1"].Value);
    dbList.Add("Field2 : " rs.Fields["Field 2"].Value);
    dbList.Add("Field3 : " (String)rs.Fields["Field3"].Value);
    dbDict.add(i,dbList);
    i+=1;
    rs.MoveNext();
}
while (rs.EOF == false);
```

Comment: Why are you intializing your list twice before it's used?

Answer (score 0):

This is because dbList is a reference type, you pass a reference to the dictionary and then call clear on that same reference that clears the internal state of the List.

Move the creation and use of `dbList` to inside the loop, then you create a new instance with every loop iteration AND do not call Clear.

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dbDict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

do
{
    List<string> dbList = new List<string>();
    dbList.Add("Field1 : " (String)rs.Fields["Field1"].Value);
    dbList.Add("Field2 : " rs.Fields["Field 2"].Value);
    dbList.Add("Field3 : " (String)rs.Fields["Field3"].Value);
    dbDict.add(i,dbList);
    i+=1;
    rs.MoveNext();
}
while (rs.EOF == false);
```